# paypal pro and asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, paypal

has anyone implemented paypal pro payflo with asp classic?

(not using a certificate that needs to be installed)

I see some asp.net examples but I am trying to find a asp classic example

I would like to do this like the authorize.net aim example where I sent a post to payapl and get a response if the card charged successfully or not

Answer (score 0):

Look into the PayPal Integration Center... [Here.](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_sample-code.html)

> Sample code for calling PayPal Web Service APIs is included with the
>   PayPal SDK. To view the samples, download and install the SDK onto
>   your computer.
>
> Once you have downloaded and installed the SDK, you will find the
>   samples in the following directories. Where provided, open the README
>   file in the directory for specific information about the samples.
>
> PayPal SDK for Classic ASP Samples are located in the
>   samples\ClassicASP directory. The actual code that forms the API
>   requests and makes the calls is located in the paypal.asp file.

The Classic ASP Samples are [here](http://paypal.github.io/sample-apps/).

Comment: My problem is that I can't install the sdk on a shared server

I am looking to do it via a xml request(https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_xmlpay_guide.pdf) - has anyone done this already that can save me time coding it?